# What is the point of the "method" method in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, there is the "method" method, which creates a method object that you can then treat as a Proc. This is useful if you wish to do metaprogramming:

```
def foobar(method_as_a_string)
   2.method(method_as_a_string).call(2)
end

foobar("+")
=> 4

foobar("-")
=> 0
```

However, normally, if you want to do such meta-programming, you would use `send` instead of method...

```
def foobar(method_as_a_string)
   2.send(method_as_a_string, 2)
end

foobar("+")
=> 4

foobar("-")
=> 0
```

What is the point of the "method" method then in Ruby?

Comment: cause you can use it like: `a = 2.method('+')` and then: `a.call(3)`, `a.call(4)`, etc..

Comment: *"which creates a method object that you can then treat as a Proc"* – Well, that's what it's for. If that's ever what you want to do, it's there to use. Is there any other method which does the same thing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `Method` object provides for all sorts of introspection and metaprogramming, including:

1. Getting the arity or parameters for the method
2. Getting the source code location for the method, which is useful in debugging or when writing tools that interact or inspect the source of the application that's running
3. Getting the receiver of the method

How and what you use those powers for is up to you.

---

For Cary, below:

```
"cat".method(:count).receiver
# => "cat"
```

Comment: @CarySwoveland There's the [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Method.html#method-i-receiver), but that's all I've got.

Comment: For the example given in the doc (`"cat".method(:count).inspect #=> "#<Method: String#count>"`) the receiver (`"cat"`) is not identified.

Answer (score 11):

You can pass a `method` result to a block, and it will call the method passing the iteratee *as arguments*.

For example, this wouldn't work:

```
[1,2,3].each(&:puts)
```

because it's calling `1.puts`, `2.puts`, etc. But this would:

```
[1,2,3].each(&method(:puts))
```

Another example:

```
arr, result = [1,2,3], []
arr.each &result.method(:push)
result # => [1,2,3]
```

Another useful thing is using it to find the source location of a method:

```
Someclass.method(:some_method).source_location
# => this will give you the file & line where it's defined
```

This is a very helpful trick when you're working with gems and want to quickly glance at their source code

Answer (score 4):

There are other aspects of metaprogramming than just working with methods directly. I wrote some code recently that needed to identify what class a method was actually defined in.

Here's a simple example:

```
class Foo
  def bar
    puts "bar"
  end
end

# to get the owner of bar method here
Foo.new.method(:bar).owner
```

I was working with a scenario where many classes were extending a single class, and in that single class I needed to know where a method was defined for tracking purposes. I wrote this in a Rails application, inside a before_filter for every method.

This has been the only time I've needed #method directly.

Answer (score 3):

I often use it when looking for documentation.

As an example :

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].slice_after{|x| x.odd? }
```

The receiver is an Array, but there's no `slice_after` in the [Array doc](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html).

It means `slice_after` is defined somewhere in :

```
Array.ancestors
#=> [Array, Enumerable, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

Instead of looking at the documentation of those classes :

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].method(:slice_after)
#=> #<Method: Array(Enumerable)#slice_after>
```

So the method is defined in [Enumerable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_after), and made available to Array objects.

Comment: this is almost the only thing I am used to using `method` for :)

Comment: Good point: `"abc".method(:dup) #=> #<Method: String(Kernel)#dup> `, but we still have to remember that `Kernel`'s instance methods are documented  in `Object`.